# How to deal with similar date formats using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, oracle

I have two weird date ranges:

```
01.01-02.01.2022
01-02.01.2022
```

In order to extract fist date in usual format (`01.01.2022`) I have to detect both situatuations using regular expressions:

For `01.01-02.01.2022`:

```
\d{2}\.\d{2}-\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}
```

And for `01-02.01.2022` (also `01-02/01/2022` or `01-02\01\22`)

```
\d{2}-\d{2}[/\.\\]\d{2}[\./\\]\d{2,4}
```

Problem is 01.***01-02.01.2022*** contains ***01-02.01.2022*** in it

What regual expression sould I use for `01.01-02.01.2022` to avoid situation when the date format is matched by both expressions?

Of course it would be easy if my strings begin with the date. ^ in in front of the expression could solve my problem. But sometimes dates are wrapped with something else.

Comment: Are these the only formats possible? Also, how consistent are they - is the year always four digits, never two? Day and month always two digits (zero-padded as needed)? No spaces around the dash, ever? Also: is the first number always the day and the second the month?

Comment: Try `(^|\D\.|[^0-9.])(\d{2}-\d{2}[/.\\]\d{2}[\./\\]\d{2,4})($|\D)` - grab Group 2 value. Actually, in Oracle regex, `[/.\]` is enough to match any of the 3 chars as you cannot use regex escapes in bracket expressions.

Comment: @mathguy There are few formats (01.01.18-02.01.18; 2018.01.01; 01.01.2022, for example). Year could be 2 or 4 digits long. Day and month always 2 digits long. Seems like there are no spaces inside dates. Day is always before month.

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew it works, thank you! You are right about escapes inside [ ]. I forgot about it.

Comment: Given the possible variations, how do you know what 03.04.05 means? Is it the third of April 2005, or is it 2003-04-May?

Comment: @mathguy, Fortunately it is impossible: 2-digit years is only used at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(^|\D\.|[^0-9.])(\d{2}-\d{2}[/.\]\d{2}[/.\]\d{2,4})($|\D)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/04RLTx/1). Grab Group 2 value.

**Details**

- `(^|\D\.|[^0-9.])` - Group 1: either start of string (`^`), a non-digit char and a dot (`\D\.`) or any char but digit and dot (`[^0-9.]`)
- `(\d{2}-\d{2}[/.\]\d{2}[/.\]\d{2,4})` - Group 2 (this is what you need to extract): 2 digits, `-`, 2 digits, `/` or `.` or `\`, two digits, `/` or `.` or `\`, two, three or four digits
- `($|\D)` - Group 3: end of string (`$`) or a non-digit char (`\D`)

If you mean to match 2 or 4 digits with `\d{2,4}`, you must replace it with `(\d{4}|\d{2})` or `\d{2}(\d{2})?`.

Comment: I think it should look like `select REGEXP_SUBSTR('01.01-02.01.2022', '(^|\D\.|[^0-9.])(\d{2}-\d{2}[/.\]\d{2}[/.\]\d{2,4})($|\D)', 1, 1, NULL, 2) as Result from dual` in Oracle.